# Matching element heights jQuery/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following construct in my HTML document:

```
<div class="content">
<section class="column"></section>
<aside class="column"></aside>
</div>
```

And I want to match the heights of the section and aside to the height of the tallest of the two. I have the following script, but it's not working, any ideas:

```
  function unifyHeights()   
    {    
        var maxHeight = 0;    
        $('div.content').children('.column').each(function(){      
        var height = $(this).outerHeight();      
        if ( height > maxHeight ) { maxHeight = height; }    
    });    
    $('.column').css('height', maxHeight);  
  }
```

Comment: Did you test if that anonymous function is called twice, with the correct children? Did you look at the values `height` gets assigned? Does `maxHeight` increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like nothing was wrong with the function in your question, because both columns get the same height when using this markup and code (taken from your Pastebin example):

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function unifyHeights()   
{    
    var maxHeight = 0;    
    $('div.content').children('.column').each(function(){      
        var height = $(this).outerHeight();      
        if ( height > maxHeight ) { maxHeight = height; }    
    });    
    $('.column').css('height', maxHeight);  
}
</script>
<style>
.content {
background-color: yellow;
}
section.column {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
aside.column {
    width: 300px;
    floaT: left;
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <section style="background-color: pink;" class="column">jldkjfls<br/><br/></section>
    <aside style="background-color: green;" class="column">jldkjfls<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></section>
<script>
    unifyHeights();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$('.column').css('height', maxHeight + 'px');`

BTW, you can replace `$('div.content').children('.column')` with`$('div.content > .column')`

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to get the maximum of a set of properties is using `.map()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var heights = $('div.content').children('.column').map(function(idx, el) {
        return $(this).outerHeight();
    }).get();

    $('.column').height(Math.max(heights));  
});
```

Comment: I must be doing something fundamentally wrong since that doesn't work either - can you see in this test document what that might be: http://pastebin.com/JqfThuQ8

Comment: @Stuart: You're not invoking that function at all, and besides, according to my console and http://api.jquery.com, `max` is not a function.

Comment: @Marcel No, it isn't -- I thought it was a native JS array method. Editing now...